# Fixed header in wordpress using beaverbuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

My website is: http://chris.money/ I am using beaver builder to set up my website.

I want a fixed header that display over the top of the header image, I have this code:

```
<div id="header">html code and/or php for menu</div>

#header { position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:100; }
```

but it's not overlaying, instead its just adding above the image.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add that css

```
.fl-page-nav-right {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```